# Apache Nifi KafkaTimestamp Creation Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm having an issue when publishing a json message to a kafka topic through a data pipeline in Apache Nifi where the timestamp is not created. Is there a way in Nifi to generate the message when an incoming message is submitted. I'm viewing the messages through the Kafka tool 2.0 and I have a back end process that using the timestamp from kafka.

Comment: Which Kafka version? Which Kafka Processor? Could you provide more information please?

Comment: Kafka 2.12 and publishing with no value set, also tried a value set with the kafka key no luck